# WebAssembly LinkError module="env"

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm running the tutorial on [webassembly.org](http://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/) and now I want to run the `hello.wasm` from my own page.
I'm compiling the code using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) as per tutorial's instructions.

Following [these instructions](http://webassembly.org/getting-started/js-api/) in my `index.html` I'm doing:

```
const instantiate = (bytes, imports = {}) =>
  WebAssembly.compile(bytes).then(m =>
    new WebAssembly.Instance(m, imports)
  )

fetch('hello.wasm')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(bytes => instantiate(bytes, {}))
```

But I get this error:

[image: RangeError]

So I tried to use `WebAssembly.instantiate()` from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate) with this code:

```
const instantiate = (bytes, imports = {}) =>
  WebAssembly.compile(bytes).then(m =>
    WebAssembly.instantiate(m, imports)
  )
```

And I get a different one:

[image: LinkError]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Let's try to narrow the issue: you don't need `compile` in your second example, only `instantiate`: it takes the `.wasm` bytes and compile+instantiates them. What is the `imports` object? Or do you leave it as default `{}`? What are your module's declared imports (from Emscripten I assume)?

Comment: even if I use the overloaded method of `instantiate`, it fails with the same error. I'm passing it an empty object as `imports` and I don't know of needed dependencies.

Comment: Emscripten already generates HTML+JS which loads `hello.wasm` for you, including the WebAssembly import object. What Emscripten generates is pretty big because it emulates an OS. The import object basically supplies all the syscalls (to JavaScript). You'd have to pass these in for the example to work... or just use the ones Emscripten already generated.

Comment: I think your comment together with @Andreas answer should be the right answer.

Comment: Great, I answered with extra info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't clear from your question, but further comments explain that you leave the import object as `{}`, leading instantiation to fail. WebAssembly uses a double namespace, where the [import object](http://webassembly.org/docs/js/#webassemblyinstance-constructor) fulfills the `WebAssembly.Module`'s [imports](http://webassembly.org/docs/modules/#imports). Each import is [specified](http://webassembly.org/docs/binary-encoding/#import-section) as module+field+kind, which the JavaScript import object must fulfill.

Emscripten already generates HTML+JS which loads `hello.wasm` for you, including the WebAssembly import object. What Emscripten generates is pretty big because it emulates an OS. The import object supplies all the syscalls (to JavaScript). You'd have to pass these in for the example to work... or just use the ones Emscripten already generated.

The code you're using is expecting a module called `env`. Emscripten contains code such as:

```
let importObject = {
  env: { foo: () => 42, bar: () => 3.14 }
};
```

That's the double namespace I mentioned earlier: `env` is a module, and `foo` / `bar` are fields. Their type is `function`. WebAssembly supports other kinds of imports and exports: table, memory, and global.

Missing a single module, or a module's field, or mismatching the kind, leads to instantiation failure as you're getting.

Comment: @Bastien, Can WASM module call the functions defined in the impoerObject.env? if possible how?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, your example module wants to import something from a module named `"env"`. However, the `imports` object you provide is empty. To make instantiation of your module succeed you need to provide an imports object of the form `{env: {...}}`, where the dots are properties corresponding to every single import made from `"env"`.

Comment: yeah, I think it too. But how can I get those dependencies? Now I'm trying to decompile the `wasm` and see what are the `import` statements.

Comment: I've updated my question with a direct reference to Emscripten, which is included in the tutorial. Although your answer is basically correct, I think that it should be completed with JF Bastien's comment which is more specific and then useful for future references.